# How does a client know the datatype of JSON RestResponse

Tags: json, xml, rest, delphi, xsd

While developing a client application using one of our existing REST services, I have the choice for using JSON or XML responses. The XML responses are described by XSD files with schema information.

With these XML Schemas I can determine what datatype a certain result must be, and the client can use that information when presenting the data to the user, or when the client asks the user to change a property. (How is quit another question btw as I cannot find any multiplatform Delphi implementation of XML that supports XSD schemas... but like i said: that's another question).

The alternative is to use a JSON response type, but then the client cannot determine the specific datatype of a property because everything is send as a string.

How would a client know that one of those properties is a index from an enumerated type, or a integer number, or an amount or a reference to another object by its ID maybe? (These are just examples)
I would think that the client should not contain "hardcoded" info on the structure of the response, or am I wrong in assuming that?

Comment: The "hardcoded" info is the context your application should know. What is the benefit of having the info that 42 is an enumeration of HumptiDumpti without knowing what is HumptiDumpti? If you get an answer you should know the question and the context.

Answer (score 3):

JSON doesn't have a rich type system like XML does, and JSON doesn't have a schema system for describing things like enumerations and references like XML does.  But JSON has only a few data types, and the general formatting of the JSON is self-describing in terms of what data type any given value is using (see the official [JSON spec](http://json.org) for more details):

1. a string is always wrapped in quotation marks:

   ```
   "fieldname": "fieldvalue"
   ```
2. a numeric value is digit characters without quotations:

   ```
   "fieldname": 12345
   ```
3. an object is always wrapped in curly braces:

   ```
   "fieldname": { ... object data ... }
   ```
4. an array is always wrapped in square braces:

   ```
   "fieldname": [ ... array data ... ]
   ```
5. a boolean is always a fixed `true` or `false` without quotations:

   ```
   "name": true
   ```

   ```
   "name": false
   ```
6. a null is always a fixed `null` without quotations:

   ```
   "name": null
   ```

Anything beyond that will require the client to have external knowledge of the data that is being sent (like a schema in XML, since XML itself does not describe data types at all).